# What's the meaning of this kind of variable declaration?

Tags: c, declaration

I saw one way that I can't understand clearly to declare a variable using C
(since it's just little part in the whole embedded system program, I've tried to reproduce it simpler below).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef volatile unsigned char XBYTE;
#define var (* (XBYTE * )(0x0100))

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    printf("the address of var is %x\n",&var);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the fragment is about the "var" which will be allocated at the address 100h, but the question is that I can't tell how it works by pointer.

Besides, is there any potential problem while making a declaration like this?

thanks

Comment: How is xdata defined? Looks like the typeded is incorrect.

Comment: `#define var (* (XBYTE *)(0x0100))` contents of (virtual) *storage location 0x0100*.

Comment: Your `var` is *not* a variable, but some l-value

Comment: Is this compiling at all?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow xdata is one of the memory types in Keil Cx51, it means using the external data memory.

Comment: Please show a [mre] of this being used in a way which can be compiled and run.

Comment: I could answer, if the typdef is clarified/fixed to be valid. But it looks very questionable ...

Comment: That snippet defines a typ `XBYTE` and declares a macro. No variables are involved so far. That macro is probably used for accessing an external memory address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the code can be compiled and is valid.

The `volatile` keyword means that the variable may change it's value without explicitely writing to it, e.g a timer register.
So `XBYTE` is a type referring to an `unsigned char`, which is `volatile`, in addition.
However, it's not referring to an actual memory location up to know, it's just the typedef for any such volatile register of type unsigned char.
This is where the `#define`comes in. If breaked down, it casts the int valued 0x0100 constant into a pointer to XBYTE. Then in a second step it defers that pointer to let one access that memory location. So we end up with a means to access volatile uchar @ 0x100.

As a remark, this is the only way to let C code refer to an explicit constant memory address without runtime overhead.